# How to effectively store large amount of content in Cordova (PhoneGap) application?

Tags: mobile, cordova

I'm working on Cordova application which contains data about approx. 3000 objects. In general data contains of title, object location, description and object image.

For now I'm storing "metadata" (location, title and id) in javascript file using object literal notation and loading it on startup. Descriptions (formatted text) are stored in seperate html files which are loaded on demand into an iframe.

Everything was fine for a while because I only had about 10 object descriptions added to project. After loading most of descriptions, application startup time increased to more than 10 seconds.

It seems that problem is that Cordova is unable to handle projects with lots of files as they all are getting processed on startup. So what techniques could be used to minimize file count without greatly increasing code complexity and improve application performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3000 objects you are probably better off storing them in a DB and then setting it up on startup of your application:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-second-day-of-phonegapping-copying.html

Comment: One thing, that maybe isn't clear from original question - app must run on all three major mobile platforms: iOS/Android/WP7. Unfortunately sqlite database isn't supported on WP7. If there won't be any better options, then probably I'll go with this solution + custom plugin for storage for WP7 (as it's platform I'm most comfortable with).